# parameter working in the code gives error how to solve this?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
 return Message(
        isMe: identity == doc.data['senderId'],
        isNear: chatroom == 'hotspot_chat' ? isNear : true,
        senderId: doc.data['senderId'],
        senderName: doc.data['senderName'],
        messageText: doc.data['messageText'],
        destination: doc.data['destination'],
        location: messageLocation,
        timestamp: messageTimestamp,
      );
    }
```

Hay guys  above is the code it gives error of the data that is in the squire brackets.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L49uU.png)

Comment: If you hover over the red squigly lines it shows an error message. What is that error message? Also: be sure search for the error message, as it's likely been covered before.

Answer (score 0):

edit your question with error appeared in console